# Finding a html tag by its content using regex (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

What I want to do is find the tag that has the string "test string" even when that tag is nested inside other tags.

HTML example:

```
<section class="test-class1"><div><p class="test-class2">something else....test string</p></div></section>
```

Regex :

```
/.*<([a-zA-Z]*).*>.*?test string/g
```

Output:

```
p
```

I'm using https://regex101.com/#javascript, for the testing;

This regex works well when the html is small, but when the size of the HTML increases, it times out.

Is there a way to improve the performance of the regex ?

Comment: How are you implementing this regular expression, on what HTML does it become problematic?

Comment: Don't use regex for this task. There are way too many pitfalls, even if the HTML is well-formed. `<b>test string</b><c foo="test string" />` or `<a>test <bold>string</bold></a>` are just two examples.

Comment: @David Thomas In this page [http://visao.sapo.pt/verde/2016-07-21-Vendas-mundiais-crescem-no-primeiro-semestre] for instance, I got the html matching the selector class="fullArticle", and tested it with that regex, then just picked a random text from the page to use in the regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`< *(\w+)[^<>]*>[^<]*(?:<[^>]*)*test string`

matches `p` in the first capturing group (`$1`). Is not possible to speed it up so much. You'd better to use pure JS functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<(\w+)[^>]+>[^>]+test string`

```
var data = '<section class="test-class1"><div><p class="test-class2">something else....test string</p></div></section>';
var regex = /<(\w+)[^>]+>[^>]+test string/
var output = regex.exec(data);
alert(output[1]);
```

[Online Regex](https://regex101.com/r/zE4jB3/2)